# How to apply Chinese Remainder Theorem for $x$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

If:

$$x \equiv 0 \pmod{17}$$ and $$x \equiv -1 \pmod{9}$$ Then how is:

$$x \equiv 17 \pmod{153}$$

I get that since $\gcd(9, 17) = 153 $ the solution will be $\pmod{153}$ but how do you get the $17 \pmod{153}$ ?

Comment: Have you looked at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Case_of_two_equations_.28k_.3D_2.29 ? It has simple examples to consider. It is the LCM of 9 and 17 that is 153 as the GCD is 1 actually.

Answer (score 2):

$ x \equiv 0\pmod{\!17}\!\iff\! x = 17\color{#c00}n.\,$ $\, {\rm mod}\ 9\!:\ {-}1\equiv x\equiv 17n\equiv -n$ $\!\iff\!$ $n\equiv 1$ $\!\iff\!$ $\color{#c00}{n = 1\!+\!9k}$

Therefore $\ x = 17\color{#c00}n = 17(\color{#c00}{1\!+\!9k}) = 17+153k$

Answer (score 1):

You start with Bézout's identity: $2\cdot 9-1\cdot 17=1$, from which you derive the basic solution:
$$x=2\cdot \color{red}{0}\cdot 9-1\cdot(\color{red}{-1})\cdot 17=17.$$

Comment: why are you specifically using $2, 9, (-1), 17$?

Comment: It's to show the particular application of the general rule: if $ua+vb=1$ is a  Bézout's relation between the coprime numbers $a$ and $b$, a solution of the system of congruences $\begin{cases}x\equiv \alpha\mod a\\x\equiv \beta\mod b\end{cases}$ is just $$x \equiv u\beta a+v\alpha b\mod ab.$$

Answer (score -1):

Hint first solve
$$ 9x\equiv 1\mod 17$$
which gives $x\equiv2\mod17$. Then solve 
$$17x\equiv1\mod 9$$
which gives $x\equiv-1\mod9$. Then you will get
$$ x\equiv 2\times0\times 9+(-1)\times(-1)\times 17=17\mod 153. $$

Comment: But $x \equiv 0 \text{ mod } 17$

Comment: @Rioghasarig, see the answer since 0 times anything is 0.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. Is your $x$ the same as his $x$? Because your reasoning implies $x \equiv 2 \mod 17$ where he said $x \equiv 0 \mod 17$. But I think I see what you're doing now.

Comment: @Rioghasarig, go to https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/numbertheory/crt.html for detail.